# Datatable show all rows gives warning table id Invalid json response

Tags: jquery, json, datatable

I have the following datatable. All works ok for the selection of the rows. Say for 10 row,20 rows and 50 rows. When comes to show all rows I get the following error message"
DataTables warning: table id=dashboardGrid - Invalid JSON response. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/1".

My codes are as below.

```
var oTable = $('#dashboardGrid').dataTable({
                    "order": [[ 1, "asc" ]],
                    "aoColumnDefs": [ { "bSortable": false, "aTargets": [ 0,1 ] }],
                        "processing": true,
                    "serverSide": true,
                    "paging": false,
                    "ajax": {
                        "url": "getReport.php",
                        "type": "POST",
                        "data": function(d) {
                            d.vID = $("#vehicleID").val()
                            d.startDateTime = startDateTimeFinal
                            d.endDateTime = endDateTimeFinal
                         }                

                    },
                    dom: 'Bfrtip',
                    lengthMenu: [
            [ 10, 25, 50, -1 ],
            [ '10 rows', '25 rows', '50 rows', 'Show all' ]
        ],
        buttons: [
           'pageLength', 'copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print',
           {
           extend: 'pdf',
                        title: 'Vehicle ID:'+$("#vehicleID").val()+'\nDate Start:',
                        text: 'Pdf',
                        orientation: 'landscape',
                        pageSize: 'A4',
                        exportOptions: {
                        columns: [ 0, 1, 2, 3, 5 ]
                        },
                        customize: function ( doc ) {
                        doc.content[1].table.widths = [
                        '5%',
                        '30%',
                        '30%',
                        '10%',
                        '10%'

                        ]
                        }
           }


        ]
                      });
```

I have tried edit with paging:false also the same.

Comment: Check returned data for valid JSON using https://jsonlint.com/

Comment: @AmitKB how to check to must I install

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the solution is that when we send at -1 some special appropriation need to be done at the sql level where do the limit of the data. So have the logic such that when its -1 remove that logic.